# Order post by custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

In advance many thanks for read this question!

I have order my post by a custom field (eslora), but when apply the filter (category) this sort is broken.

Some one know how can order my post on this way by default.

Best regards!

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin() ) {  
        return $query;
    }

    // only modify queries for 'event' post type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post' ) {     
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');   
        $query->set('meta_key', 'eslora');   
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');    
    }
    // return
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Comment: have you tried this - http://www.billerickson.net/wp-query-sort-by-meta/ ?

Comment: This is good solution for sort by two metas. I think my problem is in the template because the code is good.

Comment: have you mention template name in your template file ?

Comment: The solution: In the theme have some code to order so rewrite this function. I find this lines and remove, and my code working good!